# Pass any model extension to controller method

Tags: php, laravel, oop, inheritance, type-hinting

I have something like this:

```
class ModelA extends Model {}
class ModelB extends Model {}
class DefaultController extends Controller {
    protected function getData(Model $model) {
        return $model::where(...)->first();
    }
}
class MyControllerA extends DefaultController {
    private function show() {
        $this->getData(new ModelA);
        // Error: Must be Model, but ModelA given.
    }
}
class MyControllerB extends DefaultController {
    private function show() {
        $this->getData(new ModelB);
        // Error: Must be Model, but ModelB given.
    }
}
```

I want to pass any instance of `Model` to `function getData`, since in that method I will use only `Model` instances. When I pass an instance of `ModelA` PHP throws an error that `Model` is expected as parameter.  I cannot define `getData(ModelA $model)`, since I need any model subclass (e.g. `ModelB`) to be passed to that method.

As I know, I could do that if `Model` was `abstract`, but it isn't.

Comment: Are you sure you've accurately represented the namespaces here? What is the exact error? The underlying class doesn't need to be abstract to type hint it.

Comment: Fixed, namespace was my issue.